# Docusign Multipart Request To Create Envelope using java SDK

Tags: java, multipartform-data, docusignapi

I am trying to create envelopes (including the document and envelope definition) using Docusign java SDK. But all the docusign examples show the uploading of documents as **Base64** encoded strings embedded in JSON request body.

Does the java SDK allows uploading documents in **binary** internally using **multipart** requests ?

Can someone point me to an example that uploads docs as multipart request to Docusign using Docusign java SDK?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please UPVOTE all useful answers (including to others' questions) and CHECK the best answer to your own questions. Many thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the DocuSign SDKs only support the base64 encoded documents and do not support adding docs/creating envelopes using the `multipart/form-data` request.

I believe this is on the roadmap for DocuSign but not sure when, however the SDKs are open source so if someone code's it up they might be able to create a PR to add to the source if DS can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

[Example #10](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant/blob/master/src/main/java/com/docusign/controller/examples/EG010ControllerSendBinaryDocs.java) of the [Java Code Example launcher](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant) demonstrates how to make a multi-part request to DocuSign and send the document(s) in binary.

Comment: Thanks @Larry , I looked into the example above. But it is not using the Docusign SDK to send multipart requests. Nevertheless, it will be helpful in uploading docs in binary.

Comment: HI @SajitGupta, as Ergin noted, the SDKs do not currently support transmission of the documents in binary.